# display item of listview

Tags: android

I have a list view having several items and it is multichoice list.
I want to display the checked item of list view.
how i can do this.can anyone help me???

Comment: if checked search if the vlue is the same show item

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
m_cObjList.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // This will highlight the select view
    m_cObjAdapter.setSelected(arg2);                

  }
});
```